# ad blocker w/ vpn, or vpn with ad blocker?

Tags: vpn

Simply, (S10e no root) does a ad blockers vpn do the same as a vpn app like cyberghost? Installed adlock then wondered if there VPN being focused on blocking ads would lack in hiding traffic etc. Would it be better to get a vpn with ad blocker. I apologize if this question is simple but could not find a streight answer. Privacy would be the main thing I would like to accomplish but ad lock worked very well would I be OK keeping ad lock in the privacy dept.

Comment: VPN based ad blocker apps only use Android's VPN API (not a real VPN protocol) so that traffic goes through them before leaving the device. They filter out the malign domains/IP addresses (listed in a downloaded or user-provided hosts file) and let the rest of the traffic go out as it is. Actual VPN apps also use Android's VPN API but they encrypt the traffic with a secure protocol (like OpenVPN), may add some more obfuscation, and then send the traffic to some VPN server, which forwards it towards the actual destination. Some apps may combine the both functionalities.

Comment: Relevant comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228642/using-vpn-to-proxy-all-data-to-a-remote-ssh-gateway#comment298980_228642

Answer (score 3):

Most VPN based ad blocker Blokada don't work like traditional VPN systems, instead the VPN server is located on the same Android device. Outside of your device the traffic is just normal Internet traffic exactly as it would be without VPN based ad blocker.
The VPN based ad blocker uses the VPN system only for redirecting the traffic into the app for being able to filter the traffic. On unrooted devices the VPN system is the only way to get access to the traffic of other apps, therefore the Android VPN-client is used.

On regular VPN systems the VPN server (endpoint) is located on a server somewhere on the Internet. If the VPN is active all traffic that leaves your device is encapsulated (protected + encrypted) in a VPN data connection that is sent to the VPN server and there the data is unpacked and sent to the original server. Therefore the traffic that leaves your device is totally different and because of the additional server in-between the latency can increase depending on where the VPN server is located.

Of course it is possible to add ad blocking features to a traditional VPN.

Comment: +1 To add, if your device is rooted some Ad blocking apps that create a server as explained can also be routed through a VPN app. I have this set up Adguard +Solid soft VPN. Solid soft VPN takes care of the encryption portion (though that also has some Ad blocking features)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks I've looked into root for my unlocked S10e snapdragon as I understand it can't be rooted at this time. If you have different info plz share.

Comment: @Twillie I am not aware of Samsung rooting issues but I do hear that they can be tough, so you must be right